# Chrome: Disable prompt for repost POST-form

Tags: forms, google-chrome, post, repost

Chrome has this annoying prompt for reposting POST-forms.

While the idea of preventinmg double posts is nice, it doesn't make always sense since not every POST-form *posts* data in a forum or buys stuff in a webshop.

But Chrome has no option to disable this annoying behaviour.

Cannot "undo":

I have a POST-form where you can beautify text (sent via POST, returns beautified text). Sometimes it makes mistakes and you want to "undo" the submission so you go back in teh browser, but no! Chrome f***s you up with its annoying repost error message.

I cannot use GET since my form text is very long so i get the "URI too long" error.

How can this be fixed?

In the past the command line switch `-disable-prompt-on-repost` seemed to work, but that's no solution anyway since I cannot tell all my users to do this in order to use my website.

Answer (score 0):

To my joy this morning, this appears to be removed (the popup when re-posting), I'm running version 29.0.1547.57.  Not sure when it was removed.

However, I'm sure you redesigned your code/site long ago.

Comment: Thanks for the head-up. Didn't run across this for a while tbh.